# Index Match Where Clause Applies

Tags: excel, indexing, match, clause

I want to return the value based on index/match where clause applies.

==> Find barcode number where Price = 10 (this is variable) AND Flavour = Passion.

**So far it returns only the barcode of the first row with "10" that it finds i.e. Barcode 1 instead of 2.**

=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(F:F,MATCH(B2,I:I,0))),"",INDEX(F:F,MATCH(B2,I:I,0)))

[image: Sample]

Result so far:

[image]

Can someone advise?
Thanks!

Comment: I doubt that you can achieve this with an excel formula only (if the number of barcodes to be returned varies). You might have to implement a UDF for that.

Comment: Ah :( Yes, barcode number could either be 1,2,3... Was hoping to get away from a UDF!

Comment: Same here: I try to avoid UDFs whenever I can. How about creating a macro and run it on demand only? Maybe it doesn't have to be "life" and it would suffice to press a button to search and retrieve all relevant barcodes?

Comment: @Ralph - See below comment, simple fix "&"! Who would have thought! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible using an array formula (Hit Ctrl+Enter instead of Enter).
For example:

```
 =INDEX(F:F, MATCH("Passion"&10,G:G&I:I,0))
```

"Passion" = **1st criteria**, 10 = **2nd criteria**
*(these can be substituted by a cell reference where the criteria are saved)*
G:G = **1st criteria range**, I:I = **2nd criteria range**

On a sidenote, I would suggest the IFERROR() formula instead of IF(ISERROR()) to make it look neat and tidy.

Comment: I would also note that the website below will explain what was does with the formula above:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TablesAndLookups.aspx

Comment: @BryanDavies - Worked like a charm. Silly of me for the If(IsError) thanks for pointing that out...!